# auto evaluation of variables in pyspark in zeppelin

Tags: pyspark, emr, apache-zeppelin

I just installed Zeepelin 0.5.5 (using AWS EMR provided 'Zeppelin Sandbox'). In python blocks (%pyspark), how can I have an automatic display (evaluation) of the last variable of the block ?

I mean, in scala blocks, if I do a

```
%spark
sc
```

I get :

> res1: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@6a78beae

But in python blocks, I have to do a print().
Why this difference ? How can I have an autoeval in python ?